# Want to Create String to Post Method

Tags: ios, objective-c, string

I want to pass a string in POST method..

the string is `@"functionName=getCourses_by_category&json={"course_cat_id":"8"}"`

Comment: or should i ask to how to write a string"""";

Comment: @Seamus Campbell, dasblinkenlight, CodaFi, Carl Veazey, Monolo  My question was edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Apple's docs on [how to send POST data](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/WorkingWithHTTPAndHTTPSRequests/WorkingWithHTTPAndHTTPSRequests.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH8-SW3):

```
NSString *bodyData = @"functionName=getCourses_by_category&json={\"course_cat_id\":\"8\"}";

NSMutableURLRequest *postRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.apple.com"]];

// Set the request's content type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded
[postRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

// Designate the request a POST request and specify its body data
[postRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[postRequest setHTTPBody:[NSData dataWithBytes:[bodyData UTF8String] length:[bodyData length]]];

// Initialize the NSURLConnection and proceed as usual
```

Comment: Thanks for help Rikkles,actually my problem is i want to pass a json string like {"course_cat_id":"8"}.so when i am using NSString *body = @"functionName=getCourses_by_category&json={"course_cat_id":"8"}";,i am getting error.and its obvious,can you help.I am badly stuck with this.....

Comment: Rikkles sorry i did't saw the answer properly, I got my answer thanks for this great help, I got my solution in your first line.Thanks a lot

Comment: could you please tell me how can i set value dynamically instead of 8  in this code NSString *bodyData = @"functionName=getCourses_by_category&json={\"course_cat_id\":\"8\"}"

Comment: Read up on objective-c. This site is not meant to teach you basics but to answer specific questions. Question closed.

Comment: Ok,I will keep that  in mind...